# Modify component's view when something happens inside it's child

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

Let's say that I have two components: homepage and editor.

At the homepage component, when I click "Add post" button, then I show `editor` component.

### Homepage Component's View

```
<button (click)="showEditor()">Show editor</button>
<editorComponent *ngIf="clicked"></editorComponent>
```

`showEditor()` just set `clicked` variable as `true` and then `editor` component does appear.

## Editor Component's View

```
<div class="editor">
  ...some editor stuff
  <button (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

I'd like to hide `editor` component in `homepage` component when click `Cancel` button. To do that, I should again set `homepageComponent.clicked` as false but how to do that inside another component. Have you maybe any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add a 'clicked' value to the hp-component, which is passed to the editor-component. If the value is modified, angular will recognize this and update the values and view accordingly.

Unfortunately, JavaScript passes primitives by value, so we need to cheat a little:

```
class Wrapper {
  constructor( public value: any ) { }
}
```

Add this to the homepage-component:

```
class HpComponent {
  clicked: Wrapper = new Wrapper(false);

  showEditor() { clicked.value = true; }
}

class EditorComponent {
  @Input() clicked: Wrapper;

  cancel() { clicked.value = false; }
}
```

and pass the object to the editor-component:

```
<button (click)="showEditor()">Show editor</button>
<editorComponent *ngIf="clicked.value" [clicked]="clicked"></editorComponent>
```

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to angular2, so this might not be the best answer. AFAIK Typescript offers generics, you may implement them in the wrapper-class.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Output events.  The child component will emit an event that the parent is subscribed to through bindings.

homepage.html

```
<editor (cancelClickedEvent)="cancelEvent"></editor>
```

homepage.ts

```
cancelEvent(data) {
  // hide editor component
}
```

editor.html

```
<div class="editor">
  ...some editor stuff
  <button (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

editor.ts file

```
@Output
cancelClickedEvent: any = new EventEmitter<any>();

onCancelClick() {
  this.cancelClickedEvent.emit(data) // <-- data is whatever you want
}
```